# How to access class method from instance method in ruby on rails non activerecord model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a non activerecord rails model:

```
class Document
  attr_accessor :a, :b
  include ActiveModel::Model

  def find(id)
    initialize_parameters(id)
  end

  def save
    ...
  end

  def update
    ...
  end

  private

  def initialize_parameters(id)
    @a = 1
    @b = 2
  end
end
```

In order to find the Document, I can use:

```
Document.new.find(3)
```

So, to get it directly I changed the find method to

```
def self.find(id)
  initialize_parameters(id)
end
```

And I get the following error when I run

```
Document.find(3)
```

> undefined method `initialize_parameters' for Document:Class

How can I make this work?

Comment: Did one of the answers work for you?

Comment: Yes! Now I understood how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access an instance method from a class method that way, to do it you should instantiate the class you're working in (self) and access that method, like:

```
def self.find(id)
  self.new.initialize_parameters(id)
end
```

But as you're defining initialize_parameters as a private method, then the way to access to it is by using send, to reach that method and pass the id argument:

```
def self.find(id)
  self.new.send(:initialize_parameters, id)
end

private

def initialize_parameters(id)
  @a = 1
  @b = 2
end
```

Or just by updating initialize_parameters as a class method, and removing the private keyword, that wouldn't be needed anymore.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
class Document
  attr_accessor :a, :b

  def self.find(id)
    initialize_parameters(id)
  end

end
```

Is not trying to "access class method from instance method" as your title states. It is trying to access a (non-existent) class method from a class method.

Everything Sebastian said is spot on.

However, I guess I would ask: 'What are you really trying to do?' Why do you have `initialize_parameters` when ruby already gives you `initialize` that you can override to your heart's content? IMO, it should look something more like:

```
class Document
  attr_accessor :a, :b, :id

  class << self

    def find(id)
      new(id).find
    end

  end

  def initialize(id)
    @a = 1
    @b = 2
    @id = id
  end

  def find
    # if you want you can:
    call_a_private_method
  end

private

  def call_a_private_method
    puts id
  end

end
```

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the same behavior as an activerecord model has